# access read violation when reading from a 2d pointer array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix

for my assignment, I have to multiply two matrices together to fill a new matrix. I can only use pointer type variables. The issue I am having is an access violation when I try to multiply together. It has something to do with my 2d pointer array. I can assign values from my one dimensional `a1d` no problem, but I cannot assign the values from my two dimensional array `a2d` to matrix. I tried storing the value from `a2d` into a temporary int variable for testing, and it stores into `temp` no problem. But I still get an access violation when I try to store a value from `temp` to `matrix` I get no error if I do not try to assign `a2d` values to matrix, so it can't be an error with running out of the bounds of the array. `a2d` has values stored in it because they output to the console when it is filled in `filla2d`.  They are all in the same class together. I will attach the code below, all I have done in main is call the functions. When I check `a2d` in debug mode, it only shows me one value/address, but it outputs all of its values to the console when called so I'm not understanding.

```
class matrices
{
private:
    int* a1d[5];
    int** a2d = new int*[5];
public:
    int* matrix[50];
    matrices();
    ~matrices();
    int* filla1d();
    int* filla2d();
    int* multiply();
};
```

```
int* matrices::filla1d() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a1d[i] = new int;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        *a1d[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }

    return *a1d;
}


int* matrices::filla2d() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a2d[i] = new int[10];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            a2d[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            cout << a2d[i][j] << endl;//this outputs all of the values to the console no problem. 
        }
    }
    return *a2d;
}



int* matrices::multiply() {
    int *temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int;
    }
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        *matrix[i] = a2d[index1][index2] * *a1d[index1];//access violation thrown here
            temp = &a2d[index1][index2];//this works no problem
            *matrix[i] = *temp;//access violation thrown here

        index1++;
        index2++;
    }

int index = 0;//This is the correct style loop, not what is above
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            *matrix[index] = a2d[i][j] * *a1d[i];
            index++;
        }
    }


    return *matrix;
}
```

You can see above where I commented the location of the access violation error. It should be noted that if I set it up where I fill up matrix with only `a1d` values, there is no violation.

My problem, as pointed out in the comments, is that I was incrementing both index objects up to 50. I had to change it to be a nested for loop and I no longer get the error. I don't know why visual studio would only give me the error when using a2d and not a1d.

Comment: You have this: `int* a1d[5];` which declares `a1d` as an array of **five** int pointers; however, here: `*a1d[index1]` `index1` will go up to **fifty**, as it is incremented in each of the containing `for` loops. Not sure what you actually mean to do, so I can't really offer a full answer.

Comment: What is the value of `index1` when it throws?  As I see it, it will fail as soon as those values go above the size of `a1d`'s first dimension - 5.  That second line that "works no problem" I don't believe.  Anyway, compiler with warnings as well to be sure you haven't mixed up types.

Comment: What are the magic numbers 5, 10, and 50 supposed to represent?

Comment: @cigien a1d is a 1x5 array, a2d is a 5x10 array, and matrix is a 1x50 array.

Comment: Then the way to declare a 5x10 array would be `int a[5][10];` Why are you mixing statically sized arrays and dynamically allocated arrays?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I was so stuck on it being something I had wrong about pointers that I didn't look at how I was incrementing. Nevertheless, I never got an error except when I tried to write to ```matrix``` and I can only assume it is just a quirk of visual studio. Thanks guys. I got it to work.

Comment: @cigien  all of my arrays are dynamically allocated pointer arrays.

Comment: @killerkody you're allocating array of pointers  `a2d` with a statical size , amd you have a statically allocated array of int pointers `a1d` as well as statically allocated array of pointers `matrix`